# Printing an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to print this array of objects:

```
vStu1 = {id:"12345", name:"Dave Smith", testScore:10};
vStu2 = {id:"43531", name:"Emma Black", testScore:17};
vStu3 = {id:"97894", name:"Sue Davies", testScore:14};
arrStudents = [vStu1, vStu2, vStu3];
```

In this format:

ID: 99999 Name: XXXXXXXXXX TestScore: 99

ID: 99999 Name: XXXXXXXXXX TestScore: 99

ID: 99999 Name: XXXXXXXXXX TestScore: 99

Comment: Please explain your search effort, and why you`re not able to find a Solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach to iterate over the array and output it using a formatted string:

```
arrStudents.forEach(s => console.log(`ID: ${s.id} Name: ...`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this function:

```
vStu1 = {id:"12345", name:"Dave Smith", testScore:10};
vStu2 = {id:"43531", name:"Emma Black", testScore:17};
vStu3 = {id:"97894", name:"Sue Davies", testScore:14};
arrStudents = [vStu1, vStu2, vStu3];

/**
 * result variable is this string:
 * "ID: 12345 Name: Dave Smith TestScore: 10
 * ID: 43531 Name: Emma Black TestScore: 17
 * ID: 97894 Name: Sue Davies TestScore: 14"
 */
const result = arrStudents
  .map(student => `ID: ${student.id} Name: ${student.name} TestScore: ${student.testScore}`)
  .join('\n');
```

Comment: And why is that? Please explain what your code does, code only answers don't help users looking for how to do it